# How to save JSON Input body parameter to global variable in POSTMAN (Check image)

Tags: api, postman

How to save JSON Input body parameter to a global variable in POSTMAN (Check image)

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on the details of the question more please. That looks like the request body, given the Dynamic Variable you're using but without seeing the full data set someone could give you the incorrect reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Environment quick look (eye button) in the top right of Postman and click Edit next to Globals.
Add a variable named timestamp and give it an initial value, Save and close the environment modal.
Open a new request tab and enter [https://postman-echo.com/get?var={{timestamp}}](https://postman-echo.com/get?var=%7B%7Btimestamp%7D%7D) as the URL. Hover over the variable name and you'll see the value.
Send the request. In the response, you'll see that Postman sent the variable value to the API.

Note :No need for "$"

Comment: The `{{$timestamp}}` creates a time value at runtime, so used in context of a request param, header, body etc. Is a valid use case.

Comment: I figured he wanted to set his own timestamp not relying on the predefined $timestamp which can not be used when it’s needed in specific format or with a specific value.

Comment: Yeah, the timestamp variable is right there in the image but the question doesn't mention anything about wanted to convert this to a particular format that's needed for an endpoint. The question is about saving a particular value (It looks like a request body property), as a global variable. :D

Answer (score 0):

In order to get that value from the Request Body, you can add a simple script like this to the `Tests` tab:

```js
let depositRef = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw).api_data.deposit_reference
pm.globals.set('depositRef', depositRef)
```

This is using `pm.request.body.raw` from the `pm.*` API to grab the value from the Request Body.

You *need* to add this to the `Tests` rather than the `Pre-request Script`, as that would set the Global variable but it wouldn't resolve the dynamic variable at that point and it would just store `TX1{{$timestamp}}`.